# Forward fill on specific column for specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have data like the following. Each row is for a specific colour, associated with different numbers:

| Color | num1 | num2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | 2 |
| red | 1 | na |
| blue | 2 | na |
| blue | 2 | 3 |
| yellow | 1 | 4 |
| yellow | 1 | na |

I want to use forward fill on the `num2` column, but only forward fill within the same colors.
For example, only fill the `num2` of the first `blue` row with the previous row's `num2`, if that previous row was also `blue`.

Expected result:

| Color | num1 | num2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| red | 1 | 2 |
| red | 1 | 2 |
| blue | 2 | na |
| blue | 2 | 3 |
| yellow | 1 | 4 |
| yellow | 1 | 4 |

I have tried the following code:

```
for color in df['color'].unique():
    df[df['color'] == color]['num2']=df[df['color'] == color]['num2'].fillna(method='ffill')
```

I have also tried with `inplace=True` and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = df.replace('na', np.nan)
df['num2'] = df.groupby('Color')['num2'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Color  num1 num2
0     red     1    2
1     red     1    2
2    blue     2  NaN
3    blue     2    3
4  yellow     1    4
5  yellow     1    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
df[['Color']].join(df.groupby('Color').ffill())
```

Comment: Thanks, just had to apply to the 'num2' column